# User Posture Recognition

Tags: windows, open-source, library, c#, image-processing

Is there a library that can help detect users posture using a web cam. Preferably the library can be invoked from C#. Could you please suggest a way of achieving this. I am open to any suggestion or idea.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Also, can we assume that the user can store a modern smartphone, which includes tilt sensors, in a shirt pocket?

Comment: mostly when I work on my desktop/laptop when sitting on a chair, i usually keep my phone on the table. the mobile can be a added point of data, but cannot be the stanbdalone one.